Pulling Back a Foliation through a transverse map
I am trying to show that the pullback $f^{*}F$ of a foliation $F$ is well defined for $f: N \rightarrow M$ transverse.
I see clearly that $f^{-1}(L)$ is a embedded submanifold of $N$ and so now I just need flat charts and to show that the intersection with each submanifold is either empty or a k-slice.
How can I accomplish this last part?

Pick any $p\in M$, and consider a foliated chart $(V',\psi)$ around $f(p)\in N$. Take an open neighborhood $U'$ around $p$ such that $U'\subset f^{-1}(V')$. The map $\pi\circ \psi\circ f: U'\to \mathbb R^{n-d}$ (where $n=\dim M$ and $d=\dim F$, and $\pi$ is the projection onto the last $n-d$ coordinates ) is a submersion. So by the constant rank theorem, you can choose a chart $(U,\phi)$ around $p$ and a diffeomorphism $\varphi: V''\to V$, where $p\in V''\subset V'$, such that $\varphi\circ (\pi \circ \psi\circ f)\circ \phi^{-1}:\phi(U)\to V'$ is a projection onto the first $n-d$ coordinates. Then on the intersection of each connected component of $f^{-1}(L)$ with $U$, $\phi$ takes value in $\{c\}\times \mathbb R^{m-(n-d)}$ for some $c\in \mathbb R^{n-d}$.
